# Trying to extract certain data from an email and add it to a Sharepoint list

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to extract only Name, Age and Salary from the following data, and create a new row in a Sharepoint List for each:

[image: Example data]

I've linked the inbox and the Sharepoint list and tried a bunch of text manipulation, but can't figure it out. Even my first part of splitting the text up, returns an error:

Tried:

```
split(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'],'\n')[0]
```

Expecting:
The body of the email to be split into an array of strings, each index of the array being another line. Then I could try and split each index based on ':' as a delimiter. Not sure if it's even a good approach.

> Error: Unable to process template language expressions in action
> 'Create_item' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template
> language expression 'split(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'],'\n')[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAfmr.png)'
> cannot be evaluated because array index '1' is outside bounds (0, 0)
> of array. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage
> details.'.

Raw output from trigger in PA:

Record ID: 4067055\r\nName: Smith, Erin Rachelle\r\nTotal Hours: 7.5\r\nCreated Date: 17-JAN-2023\r\nEscalation Date: 31-JAN-2023\r\nEscalated to you By:"

JSON Output from initial email trigger (Sorry, I didn't know I could do that):

```
{
  "headers": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "Retry-After": "3600",
    "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "x-ms-request-id": "4411aed8-30d9-4f63-a11c-d0d051ecc3ae;5e807a75-caa1-40e1-a697-cb6d993923d3",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "Location": "https://australia-001.azure-apim.net/apim/office365/shared-office365-16c3af54-48d7-478e-adaf-b3aee0bd4b11/v3/Mail/OnNewEmail?folderPath=Inbox&importance=Any&fetchOnlyWithAttachment=false&includeAttachments=false&subjectFilter=timelog&LastPollInformation=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%2bIn0%3d",
    "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=75eb715df977f9cc8747c6e93018236935309083a7acad6cd06cb0ebad592e80;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=office365-ase.azconn-ase.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=75eb715df977f9cc8747c6e93018236935309083a7acad6cd06cb0ebad592e80;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=office365-ase.azconn-ase.p.azurewebsites.net",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
    "x-ms-apihub-obo": "false",
    "Date": "Tue, 07 Feb 2023 02:22:12 GMT",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Expires": "-1",
    "Content-Length": "1944"
  },
  "body": {
    "id": "AAMkADVkMTJmYTBjLTk4ZmUtNDRlMy04ZjhkLTg5MTY2ZjcyMmNhMQBGAAAAAACSejOz7iSdQb_vjnzPa_yjBwCia66Dw5tlSb-mI709rlpDAAAAAAEMAACia66Dw5tlSb-mI709rlpDAAAGMFgNAAA=",
    "receivedDateTime": "2023-02-07T02:21:54+00:00",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "internetMessageId": "<SYBPR01MB43796626ED48609438E94E9CB0DB9@SYBPR01MB4379.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com>",
    "subject": "timelog",
    "bodyPreview": "Record ID: 4067055\r\nName: Smith, Erin Julia\r\nTotal Hours: 7.5\r\nCreated Date: 17-JAN-2023\r\nEscalation Date: 31-JAN-2023\r\nEscalated to you By:",
    "importance": "normal",
    "conversationId": "AAQkADVkMTJmYTBjLTk4ZmUtNDRlMy04ZjhkLTg5MTY2ZjcyMmNhMQAQAPGPmzZrjddNiZO7kqeXB4I=",
    "isRead": false,
    "isHtml": true,
    "body": "<html><head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)\"><style>\r\n<!--\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\"}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri}\r\np.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0cm;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif}\r\nspan.EmailStyle17\r\n\t{font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:windowtext}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{}\r\n-->\r\n</style></head><body lang=\"EN-AU\" link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\" style=\"word-wrap:break-word\"><div class=\"WordSection1\"><div><div><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-size:10.0pt; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:black\">Record ID: 4067055<br>Name: Smith, Erin Julia<br>Total Hours: 7.5<br>Created Date: 17-JAN-2023<br>Escalation Date: 31-JAN-2023<br>Escalated to you By:</span></p></div></div></div></body></html>",
    "from": "email@email.com",
    "toRecipients": "email@email.com",
    "attachments": []
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you paste the EXACT body of the email in to the question?  Not what it looks like externally, I'm talking about what it looks like in the trigger in PA.

Comment: "Record ID: 4067055\r\nName: Smith, Erin Rachelle\r\nTotal Hours: 7.5\r\nCreated Date: 17-JAN-2023\r\nEscalation Date: 31-JAN-2023\r\nEscalated to you By:"

Comment: Please edit and add it to your question and please include the entire json.

Comment: That's not the entire JSON.  From your trigger, go to the outputs and copy and paste the whole lot in.  Be sure to mask anything you don't want us to see.  Much easier to provide a complete solution is you can manage to do what I'm asking.

Comment: Edited to include that. Sorry, I didn't realise I could do that. Shame

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, with the JSON you provided, there's no doubt that the easiest way to process the data is to use the `bodyPreview` property, not the `body` property.

That property gives you a much more cut down, easier view of your data.

Now on that, if it were me, I'd be doing the following.

**Firstly**, I created a variable with your entire payload so I could use it in later steps.

**Next**, the `Initialize Body Preview` step in the results below uses the following expression ...

```
variables('Trigger Data')?['body/bodyPreview']
```

**Next**, you can split up that string by line break.  This is where you need to do some trickery though.

This is the expression that you need to enter ...

```
split(variables('Body Preview Data'), '\r\n')
```

... the issue is, if you enter that into the expression editor, it'll actually store the expression like this ...

```
split(variables('Body Preview Data'), '\\r\\n')
```

... but that won't work for you.  To overcome this, go into the **Code View** and change the expression to remove the double backslashes.

That will then give you the following result.

[image: Result]

From here, you can loop over the array and split it up again by colon and process each item as you need.